# GridBagLayout ipadY and positioning

Tags: java, swing, gridbaglayout

I have a JFrame that adds a pane in the top-left corner of the window. That works fine. For some reason my gridbaglayout that composes the pane that goes in the top-left corner doesn't exactly behave like I would want it too.

The first three buttons I add are inside the first y row and added horizontally, but the informationPane that I add to gridY = 1 doesn't go to the next line, it just gets added to the right just like the buttons.

Also, I had to use set preferred size on each button because iPadY wasn't expanding the buttons vertically.

```
private JPanel setUpTop()
{
    JPanel pane = new JPanel();
    pane.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 2));

    JPanel controlPane = new JPanel();
    pane.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
    GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();


    controlPane.setBackground(Color.RED);

    c.gridx = 0;
    c.gridy = 0;
    previousSongBT = new JButton("<<");
    previousSongBT.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(CTRL_BT_WIDTH, CTRL_BT_HEIGHT));
    controlPane.add(previousSongBT, c);


    c.gridx = 1;
    c.gridy = 0;
    playBT = new JButton(">");
    playBT.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(CTRL_BT_WIDTH, CTRL_BT_HEIGHT));
    controlPane.add(playBT, c);


    c.gridx = 2;
    c.gridy = 0;
    nextSongBT = new JButton(">>");
    nextSongBT.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(CTRL_BT_WIDTH, CTRL_BT_HEIGHT));
    controlPane.add(nextSongBT, c);

    c.gridx = 0;
    c.gridy = 1;
    c.weighty = 1;
    c.gridwidth = 3;
    c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.PAGE_END;
    JPanel informationPane = new JPanel(); 
    informationPane.add(new JButton("Bottom pane"));
    informationPane.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
    controlPane.add(informationPane, c);

    pane.add(controlPane);
    return pane;
}
```

Here's the code that adds that pane :

```
//Top-Left
    c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.FIRST_LINE_START;
    c.insets = new Insets(20,20,0,0);  //top padding

    c.gridx = 0;
    c.gridy = 0;
    c.weightx = 1;
    c.weighty = 0.5;
    this.getContentPane().add(setUpTop(), c);
```

Here's a picture for more clarity, I want the green panel to be below the three other buttons:

[image]

Comment: I'm not to steady with gridbag, but have you tried setting gridy to a larger value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of

```
JPanel controlPane = new JPanel();
pane.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
```

It should read

```
JPanel controlPane = new JPanel();
controlPane.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
```

shouldn't it??